# Python module psycopg2 cannot find a reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I installed psycopg2 module because I want to send blob file to database. But I'm getting an error.

```
AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Here is my code, what's the problem?

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='SECRET', user='SECRET',
                            password='SECRET', host='SECRET',
                            port=5432)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT gen_random_uuid();")
id = cursor.fetchone()[0]

drawing = open("cat.jpg", 'rb').read() 
conn.execute("INSERT INTO files(uuid, filename, data) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)", (id, "cat.jpg", 
psycopg2.Binary(drawing)))
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second execute uses the connection instead of the cursor.
Replace this line:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO files(uuid, filename, data) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)", (id, "cat.jpg", psycopg2.Binary(drawing)))
```

with:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO files(uuid, filename, data) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)", (id, "cat.jpg", psycopg2.Binary(drawing)))
```

should fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you should install the package `pip install psycopg2-binary` following the installation [page](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) and I quote

> You can also obtain a stand-alone package, not requiring a compiler or external libraries